# How do I change only one variable into "p" tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the quantity of multiple products displayed in separate

tags using JavaScript. Initially, the quantity of the first three products is set to 10, and the quantity of the fourth product is 5. When I press the button, I want to increase the quantity of all products by 1. However, my current code is not working as expected.

Here's my code:

```js
class Product {
  #count;
  constructor(name, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.#count = count;
  }
  getCurrentCount() {
    return this.#count;
  }
  static add() {
    products.forEach((item) => {
      item.#count++;
      return updatedProductsList();
    });
  }
}

function getProduct(name) {
  productCount++;
  name = new Product(name, 10);
  products.push(name);
}

const printProductsList = () => {
  const productsContainer = document.querySelector("div");
  
  document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = `Number of products: ${products.length}`;
  
  products.map((item) => {
    const productElement = document.createElement("div");
    productElement.innerHTML = `<p>${
      item.name
    } <span>${item.getCurrentCount()}</span></p>`;
    productsContainer.append(productElement);
  });
};

const updatedProductsList = () => {
  products.map((item) => {
    document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach((e) => {
      e.innerText = `${item.getCurrentCount()}`;
    });
  });
};

const products = [];
let productCount = 0;
let apple = getProduct("Apple");
let orange = getProduct("Orange");
let avocado = getProduct("Avocado");

let watermelon = new Product ('Watermelon', 5)
products.push(watermelon)

printProductsList();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
     :root {
      --bg-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: var(--bg-color);
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    div {
      margin-top: 3rem;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    .product {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="product">
    <h2 id='products'>
      `Number of products: ${products}
    </h2>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="Product.add()">Increase the quantity by one</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue seems to be in the Product.add() method or the updatedProductsList() function. I suspect that my approach for updating the quantities in the p tags is incorrect. Can someone please guide me on how to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: I probably added the code incorrectly, because the button "Run code snipped" could not work. So, I added new post and link to CodePen inside it. But I can see that someone has rewritten my post because it works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `updatedProductsList`. For each product, you're updating every `span` with the `getCurrentCount()` in this loop. On the loop's last iteration, it updates all `span`s with the count of the last item, which is why `6` is written to the page for all products.

```
const updatedProductsList = () => {
  products.map((item) => {
    document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach((e) => {
      e.innerText = `${item.getCurrentCount()}`;
    });
  });
};
```

The underlying data in `products` has the correct counts as demonstrated by breakpoint debugging or `console.log(products);` in `updatedProductsList`. So the fix for this could be to use the index of the `span` tag to determine which `item` you're looking at, and then only updating that `span`:

```
const updatedProductsList = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach((e, index) => {
      e.innerText = `${products[index].getCount()}`;
  });
};
```

Note: I also cleaned up some other code in the below snippet. I removed `productCount` because it wasn't being updated correctly (it was only increasing with `getProduct`, not `products.push(new Product(...))`). I also changed `getCurrentCount()` to `getCount()` to better fit getter/setter method names (*current* is implied, as you're always retrieving the current value).

```js
class Product {
  count;
  constructor(name, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
  }
  getCount() {
    return this.count;
  }
  static add() {
    products.forEach((item) => {
      item.count++;
    });
    updatedProductsList();
  }
}

function getProduct(name) {
  name = new Product(name, 10);
  products.push(name);
}

const printProductsList = () => {
  const productsContainer = document.querySelector("div");
  
  document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = `Number of products: ${products.length}`;
  
  products.map((item) => {
    const productElement = document.createElement("div");
    productElement.innerHTML = `<p>${
      item.name
    } <span>${item.getCount()}</span></p>`;
    productsContainer.append(productElement);
  });
};

const updatedProductsList = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach((e, index) => {
      e.innerText = `${products[index].getCount()}`;
  });
};

const products = [];
products.push(new Product("Apple", 1));
products.push(new Product("Orange", 3));
products.push(new Product("Avocado", 5));
products.push(new Product ('Watermelon', 10));

printProductsList();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
     :root {
      --bg-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: var(--bg-color);
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    div {
      margin-top: 3rem;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    .product {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="product">
    <h2 id='products'>
      `Number of products: ${products}
    </h2>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="Product.add()">Increase the quantity by one</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's probably also better to use `document.querySelectorAll("#products > span")`, as `document.querySelectorAll("span")` returns a collection of all `<span>` elements in the entire document.

Comment: Agreed, this likely isn't a scalable solution if it's part of a page with other `span`s, or even if "remove product" functionality is added (indexes could become out of sync), but it works well enough for this example. A cleaner fix would be to add `id="<item.name>"` to each `<p>` (you'd need to account for spaces or other special characters, so maybe a new `item.id` property?) so you can select the specific tag to update without having to rely on indexes lining up.